# Display Playstore and ios button based on device in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a react js(not react native) website where I have two buttons for playstore and Ios. Now my requirement is that if a user opens the website in android mobile the ios button should be hidden and it will show only playstore same vice versa case in iphone device where ios button will be displayed and playstore button will remain hidden without changing the desktop view where both buttons will show up in react..

Answer (score 1):

Try this. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-device-detect. In API you can find some useful data.